# Pass Subview to subclassed UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, subview, viewcontroller

I have a subclassed UIView with a special behavior.

It is a custom class of a ViewController xib view. It contains a subview, which is *currently* created programmatically.

My question is; how to pass a subview ***either*** from the xib ***or*** from one created programmatically in the viewController via initWithFrame or initWithCoder to my subclassed view? (Right now it simply acts through the view, not initiated at all in the VC.)

I would share code, but I don't know that it's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `initWithFrame` method:

```
SubclassedView *view = [[SubclassedView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

Be sure to import `#import "SubclassedView.h"`

Comment: Thank you. The other way turned out to be having the nib view's class set to the subclassed view's name.